# Why is bootstrap 4 tooltip detached from link, and how can I fix it?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I've made a website template that has a sticky footer. It uses one of the common approaches to sticky footers, and I've used it many times. Because the template is using bootstrap 4 (now beta), it provides an easy way to have a nice styled tooltip. The problem is that if the page content pushes the footer down, then the tooltip detaches from the link it's supposed to be attached to.

I'd really like the tooltip to be independent of the quantity of page content, but I've tried all kinds of things and can't figure out what's wrong and how to fix it. I'd like to ask that you do not recommend that I use a different type of sticky footer. It's important that I keep the sticky footer CSS and related HTML intact.

I just need to know why the tooltip detaches when the page content pushes the footer down, and how to keep the tooltip attached no matter how much page content exists.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/skunkbad/pen/prrOWR

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <main class="main">
        <p>Please scroll</p><p>down, and</p><p>see that</p><p>there is a</p><p>link in the</p><p>footer.</p><p>The link has</p><p>a bootstrap tooltip</p><p>applied. The problem</p><p>is that if the</p><p>content in this #main</p><p>div is large </p><p>enough to start</p><p>pushing the footer down,</p><p>then the tooltip detaches</p><p>from the link.</p>
    </main>
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!">Hover over me and see that the tooltip is about 100px above me.</a>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 -75px;
}

.push {
  height: 75px;
}

.footer {
    background: red;
  height: 75px;
}

.footer a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

JS (jQuery):

```
$('footer a').tooltip();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While playing around with this issue, I found that when the CSS giving html and body a height of 100% was removed, the tooltip started to behave. Because bootstrap 4 beta uses popper for their tooltips, I searched Google for popper bugs related to height of 100% on html or body, and there was one.

According to comments on the bug, the version of popper.js recommended by bootstrap has a bug that is not present in some older versions, and at least for right now, my solution was to revert to an older version of popper.js.

Popper bug report:
https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/issues/302

Older version of popper.js that works as it should for body and html with height 100%:
v1.9.3